# Mapping solution. Is there self hosted ones and which one to pick?

Tags: c#, silverlight, mapping

I'm looking for mapping software similar to Google Maps or Bing Maps but I'd like to get something off the shelf that I can install on server and not pay $10000 per year.

It is going to be Silverlignt but for now if I can install it and run as web service for use with any client - will be great. I found something Map Suite software that will do that but not sure of their track record, etc.
Do you have any suggestion on other products? Is there any free open source solutions I can use?

Requirements is pretty simple:

1. Geocoding
2. driving distance between points
3. Processing #1 and #2 in batches
4. Mapping of points and path/directions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try http://www.openstreetmap.org/

Comment: and follow this discussion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1875255/open-source-poi-database